# Undefined variable: post (View: E:\xamp\htdocs\lsapp\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel, and getting this error though tried every possible sites and google searches. I even tried previous queries solution from stack overflow, but was unable to solve.

this is my PostController.php:

```
`public function getData()
{
    $post['post']=DB::table('students')->get();
    if(count($post)>0){
        return view('index',['Post'=>'$post'] );
    }
    else{
        return view('index');
    }
}`
this is my controller
```

This is my index.blade.php:

```html
`@foreach($post as $value)
 <tr>
 <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
 <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
 <td>{{$value->address}}</td>
 <td>{{$value->number}}</td>
 <td><a href="" ><button>Edit</button></a>&nbsp; <a href="" > 
 <button>Delete</button></a></td>
 </tr>`
```

This is my blade:

```
Route::get('/index','PostController@getData');
```

this is my route

please help in this queries, i am having a lots of problem

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your code. I would recommend you go through [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/) and [first 2 PSRs](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

As error clearly states that there is not a variable **$post** in the view. In else you are not sending the **$post** variable and in if you are sending the $post variable with a capital P but you are accessing it using lower case p in your view. So the variable is not available in any case in the view that's why it is showing that error.

PHP variables are case sensitive and do not use the quotes around php variable (the one with $ sign) in the parameters that you are passing to the view.

```
return view('index',['Post'=>'$post'] );
```

Above statement should be written as

```
 return view('index',['post'=>$post] );
```

also update your controller method and I don't know why are you using associative array ($post['post']).

```
public function getData()
{
    $post = DB::table('students')->get();
    return view('index',['post'=>'$post'] );
}
```

Comment: Rafay Hassan , i just tried using @if($post), but still same error is shown

Comment: @SagarBasnet I have updated the answer check now. let me know your error still exist

Comment: @SagarBasnet if you problem is solved please accept the answer. click the check mark below vote arrows

Comment: `$post` instead of `'$post'`.

Answer (score 0):

I identified this problem. You send the posts variable in the index function.

```
public function index(){
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}
```

But most likely you get this error when you want to create a new post, so here the store function is executed and the index function is not executed in the controller, because the store function is responsible for storing form information. Then you edit this function as follows.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $post = new Post();
    $post->title = $request->input("title");
    $post->description = $request->input("description");
    $post->save();


    $posts = Post::all(); //Send posts in compact
    return view("posts.index", compact($posts));
}
```

Excuse me for the typing problem, I am a Persian speaker ❤